# Генерация уникальных ID

Tags: c++

Всем привет! Хочу генерировать уникальные ID для объектов. ID объектов буду записывать в файл. Хочу генерировать можно так сказать глобальный ID, который 1 раз сгенерировал для объекта и больше он никогда не меняется, то-есть вариант со static полем и генерацией в конструкторе мне наверно не подходит. Хочу что-то по типу UUID, но не хочу использовать сторонние библиотеки. Можете посоветовать или дать какие то идеи как самому генерировать ID, может если брать текущую дату и еще что-то...

Comment: Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72358504/4928642. Linux: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25818357/4928642.

Comment: Не понял, а чем static поле с инкрементом в конструкторе не угодило?

Comment: MD5 от текущего времени в наносекундах

Comment: 128 бит из `std::random_device` + `std::time` + `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count()` + static-счётчик.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, так как мне нужно записывать этот id в файл, а static поле с инкрементом в конструкторе можно сказать динамически генерирует эти id. Например если у меня есть массив из 3 объектов, с id 0, 1, 2. И я удалю объект с id 0, то после перезагрузки программы объект который был с id 1 станет с id 0, а объект с id 2 станет 1. А мне нужно чтобы id объектов оставались всегда одинаковыми.

Comment: @avp А почему не само время?

Comment: @Mikhailo, плохо подумал, когда писал коммент. Действительно нет смысла делать MD5 только от времени. Наверное, для глобальной уникальности стоит вычислять MD5 от MAC-адреса + время в секундах с наносекундами (из `clock_gettime()`). Если желательно, чтобы ID монотонно возрастали, то MD5 брать не надо, только MAC + время

Comment: Спасибо за ваши ответы, еще вопрос такой: вот я создал класс например `IdGenerator` который имеет метод `Generate()` возвращающий сгенерированный `id` типа `string`, как мне его корректно использовать? Например у меня есть класс `Человек`, и есть метод `AddHuman()` который реализует добавление новых людей в массив людей. Можно ли сделать поле `string id` у Человека, и в этом том методе вызывать метод `Generate()` класса `IdGenerator` и то что он вернул записывать в поле `id` у человека? Или как правильнее будет сделать?

Comment: То-есть в методе `AddHuman()` создавать объект класса `IdGenerator` у него вызывать метод `Generate()`

Answer (score 0):

Ну повесьте на него счётчик и никаких гвоздёв. Или вручную распределяйте.